# Wie nennt man eine Person, die viel jammert?

Tags: adjective, vocabulary, colloquial

wie würde man (umgangssprachlich) jemanden nennen, der viel jammert? Ist das Wort „jammerig“ hier gebräuchlich?

Answer (score 7):

"Jammerig" habe ich noch nie gehört (und würde deswegen behaupten, dass es nicht gebräuchlich ist).

In abwertender Art und Weise würde man eine Person, die viel jammert, "**[Jammerlappen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Jammerlappen)**" oder (nicht sehr verbreitet, aber mit "jammern" 'direkt verwandt') "Jämmerling" nennen.

Vielleicht noch ein Hinweis:
das Wort "jämmerlich" bezieht sich eher auf "Anlässe zum Jammern".

> "Das Auto war in einem **jämmerlichen** Zustand." (schlechten Zustand)

oder

> "Es herrschte eine ganz **jämmerliche** Kälte." (sehr kalt)

Falls dich das interessiert, gibt es hier [Jämmerlichkeit](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Jaemmerlichkeit) und hier [jämmerlich](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/jaemmerlich) mehr Informationen dazu.

Comment: Das Adjektiv *»jammerig«* habe ich noch nie gehört, aber auch das Substantiv *»Jämmerling«* ist mir ebenso unbekannt. Für jemanden, der viel jammert, kenne ich nur die Bezeichnung *»Jammerlappen«.*

Comment: Vielen Dank! :)

Comment: "Jammerlappen" kenne ich nur in der Bedeutung einer Person, über die (bzw. deren Zustand und deren fehlende Motivation) man jammern kann. Das ist mE etwas ganz anderes als jemand, der selber viel jammert. [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Jammerlappen) scheint mir da zuzustimmen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper tut mir leid, aber ich kann das auch aus der DWDS-Quelle nicht herauslesen..

Comment: @choXer: Wo genau steht denn in DWDS etwas davon, dass der Jammerlappen selber jammert?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper "  Jammerlappen m. ‘wehleidig klagender Mensch, Feigling’ (berlin. 19. Jh.) " z.B.

Comment: @choXer: Interessant. Ich kenne die Verwendung wie gesagt gänzlich anders; vielleicht gibt es da regionale Unterschiede. Viele Quellen, die ich finde, sind in der Tat nicht besonders eindeutig. Z.T. wird dem Jammerlappen nachgesagt, er jammere selber; andererseits wird das Wort vorrangig als Synonym zu "Feigling", "Schwächling", "Waschlappen" usw. dargestellt, welche ja alle rein auf die Schwäche abzielen, nicht darauf, dass sich die Person selber darüber auch beschwert.

Answer (score 6):

- Heulsuse
- Jammerlappen
- Memme
- Meckerliese, Meckerziege
- Lamentierer
- Nölziege
- Beckmesser
- Räsoneur

Comment: Eine Memme ist ja ein Feigling oder Schwächling. Dass er auch jammert ist denkbar, aber nicht notwendig.

Comment: "Jammerlappen" kenne ich nur in der Bedeutung einer Person, über die (bzw. deren Zustand und deren fehlende Motivation) man jammern kann. Das ist mE etwas ganz anderes als jemand, der selber viel jammert. [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Jammerlappen) scheint mir da zuzustimmen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Nein, ein "Jammerlappen" ist jemand, der viel jammert. Ich kann unter dem gegebenen Link auch keinen Anhaltspunkt für deine Interpretation finden

Comment: @Sentry: Nun, die Definition bei DWDS besagt: "feiger, willensschwacher Mensch". Wer willensschwach ist, nimmt ja das Elend eher resigniert hin, statt sich in irgendeiner Form darüber zu beschweren. Auch ist in der Synonymgruppe der Begriff "Schwächling" als Hauptform ausgewiesen, welcher ja auch rein auf die persönliche unzulänglichkeit des Beschriebenen abzielt und keine Aussage darüber zulässt, ob der Beschriebene diesbezüglich nun viel lamentiert. Wie von [choXer](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/61707#comment150541_61709) aufgezeigt, definieren einzelne Quellen das Wort ...

Comment: ... jedoch auch gänzlich anders und bringen es in der Tat damit in Zusammenhang, dass nicht *über* den Jammerlappen gejammert wird, sondern dass *er* es ist, der jammert. Ggf. ist der Begriff also in der Tat (regional unterschiedlich?) mit unterschiedlichen Bedeutungen belegt.

Answer (score 1):

Ich schlage "Jammerer" vor. Dieses Wort ist gewiss nicht weit verbreitet, trifft es aber genau (ähnlich wir der "Nörgler" zum Verb "nörgeln" gehört).

Schöne Beispiele findet man [hier](https://www.power-slide-coaching.de/2018/02/16/jammerer-sind-energievampire/) und [hier](https://www.handelsblatt.com/unternehmen/management/chefberaterin/die-chef-beraterin-schluss-mit-der-jammerei/11990748.html?ticket=ST-9502560-cksfGMNyneIBCHuuRRFr-ap5).